# Data is showing as NULL unless i make a small change to force a hot reload. Why isn't it there initially?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have been messing around with Flutter and trying to create a basic app to see how it all works, and I have a screen which should show the details of the single registered user. The issue is, when I first navigate to the screen the 'user' object is null, it is only if i make minor change, say to some text to force a hot reload, the user data appears as if by magic.

here is my getUser function, which seems to work as expected:

```
Future<User> getUser() async {
  final UserDao userDao = UserDao();
  final String authenticationToken = await userDao.getUserToken(0);
  final response = await http.get(
    'http://vps746196.ovh.net/api/user/',
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'token $authenticationToken'},
  );
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseJson[0]);
  return User.fromDatabaseJson(responseJson[0]);
}
```

and here is my the user screen:

```
class UserScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _UserScreenState createState() => _UserScreenState();
}

class _UserScreenState extends State<UserScreen> {

  User user = User();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getThatUser();
    print(user.username);
  }
  _getThatUser() async {
    print('Getting that user');
    user = await getUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('The Yard Users'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
              child: Text(
                'Username: ${user.username}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // Logout button
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(34.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.16,
                  child: LogoutButton()
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seems as though the new screen is loading before the data has been assigned to the user variable. I thought the whole point in using the await command was so this didn't happen. Clearly I have much to learn, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `FutureBuilder` widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your `Future` wasn't yet done before the `Text` widget was rendered.

You can fix by:

1. Show a progress indicator if the `username` is `null` and show the `username` if it is not `null`.

```
           Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
              child: user.username == null
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator() // show an indicator if the username is still null
                  : Text(
                      'Username: ${user.username}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
```

OR

2. Use a `FutureBuilder` widget:

```
class UserScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserScreenState createState() => _UserScreenState();
}

class _UserScreenState extends State<UserScreen> {

 Future<User> futureUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureUser = getUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('The Yard Users'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder( // use a future builder widget
          future: futureUser, // assign the future
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                // show your layout if future is done
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Username: ${snapshot.data.username}', // get the username from the snapshot
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Logout button
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(34.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.16,
                        child: LogoutButton()),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator(); // show a progress indicator while future is executing
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

The `future` shouldn't be called in the `build` method, why ? [Read here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#why-is-fetchalbum-called-in-initstate)

Comment: For the first solution `setState` has to be added into `_getThatUser`. For the second, the Future should be obtained in `initState`, it shouldn't be called in build.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `future` kept in the `build` method, edited my answer. :-).

Comment: Did the second option as I feel I need to be using FutureBuilder - thanks a lot guys works a charm.

Comment: Literally never knew I had to accept answers, thanks again!